# Where can you ask questions on Tesseract?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was wondering which site would be best suited for such a question like below:

I'm doing OCR work on a Raspberry Pi system using C# and Tesseract and I would just like to know would you use Tesseract to detect whether a mark has been made in a specific part of a document? It does not need to convert the text, it only has to detect whether a mark has been made.

Comment: What's the actual question about? It would probably help if you not only included the technology you work with, but also the types of questions you have about that technology, in your question :)

Comment: I would just like to know you would use tesseract to detect whether a mark has been made in a specific part of a document? It does not need to convert the text, it only has to detect whether a mark has been made.

Comment: I'm not sure about the C# bit but tesseract and raspberry pi give [some network wide hits](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=tesseract++raspberry+pi)

Comment: So it looks like you expect answers that implement a working solution ib C# for the high-level requirement as stated where the implementation should also work on a Raspberry Pi. Is that the gist of what you're asking for? Or do you have a C# solution already going with tesseract and just facing a specific problem?

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow enjoys a large Tesseract community, so a question which contains:

- A complete description of the problem,
- Relevant code and/or data to help reproduce the problem locally, and
- An earnest attempt at a solution (e.g. I tried to do X to identify a mark, but I wound up not seeing it; here's my code, where am I going wrong?)

...would be on-topic and suitable for the site.

**Anything less than this would not be suitable for the site!**